# Error in my web pagr only with chrome and mobile

Tags: html, css, mobile

**Hello**! i have problem with Css, 
It is working perfectly with firefox, open and close my menu (burger menu)
With chrome and with mobile... dont working.. 
when clicked the button does not open the menu, 
anyone has ever had such a mistake?

```js
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

// Close the dropdown if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {

    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.dropbtn 
{
    background-color: #50b7d8;
    border: medium none;
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding: 0;
}

.dropbtn:hover, 
.dropbtn:focus 
{
  background-color: #3e8e41;
}

.dropdown 
{
    box-shadow: 0 -4px 10px;
    float: right;
    position: relative;
}

.dropdown-content 
{
    background-color: #50b7d8;
    border-radius: 0 10px 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    display: none;
    left: 10px;
    min-width: 160px;
    overflow: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 48px;
}

.dropdown-content a 
{
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown a:hover 
{
  background-color: #f1f1f1
}

.show 
{
  display:block;
}

#myDropdown .current.active a 
{
    background-color: #93c524;
    border-radius: 0px;
    color: #fff;
    padding-left: 4px;
    padding-right: 4px;
}

#myDropdown .current.active 
{
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
    border-top: 1px solid #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <div class="dropbtnblock">
    <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">Apri</button>
  </div>
  <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
    miomenu
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is the console showing any errors?

Comment: @Epodax It is done

Answer (score 0):

This is my site, the burger menu is  with resolution max-width : 790px
i have created template for joomla..

[Link](http://superadministrator.net/giocoresponsabile/index.php)